# CircleCI circle.yml file - how to checkout differently with different branches

Tags: maven, build, continuous-deployment, circleci

Here is our circle.yml file:

```
machine:
  services:
    - docker
  java:
    version: openjdk7

checkout:
  override:
    - step 1
    - step 2
    - step 3

dependencies:
  pre:
    - step a
    - step b

  override:
    - step i
    - step ii
test:
  override:
    - echo "test"

deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - step one
      - step two
  staging:
    branch: /release-.*/
    commands:
      - step one
      - step two
      - step three
```

As you can see we already do different deploy steps from production to staging.
Is it possible to defrintiate whitin outher  sections as well? for example in the checkout section like so:

```
machine:
  services:
    - docker
  java:
    version: openjdk7

checkout:
 prod: 
  branch: /release-.*/
  override:
    - step 1
    - step 2
    - step 3
 stage:
  branch: master
  override:
    - different step 1
    - different step 2
    - different step 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that. But what I know you can do is executing a shell script like

```
prod: 
   branch: /release-.*/
   commands:
      - ./release.sh
```

Then, inside the release file, you can apply your rules.